# Converting Google Chart into Image

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

I'm trying convert a Google Chart into a image like [this link](https://gist.github.com/1333906) but I don't understand about the line

`var chartArea = chartContainer.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].contentDocument.getElementById('chartArea');`

The code generated by the Google Chart, doesn't create any `iFrame` or elements called `chartArea`

Can someone help me ?

**UPDATED**

Follow the source of the   generated by the chart, when I transform him into a image

```
http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=lc&amp;chs=500x200&amp;chtt=Acessos%20ao%20im%C3%B3vel%20dos%20ultimos%20sete%20dias&amp;chxt=x%2Cy&amp;chxl=0%3A%7C24%2F01%7C25%2F01%7C26%2F01%7C27%2F01%7C28%2F01%7C29%2F01%7C30%2F01%7C1%3A%7C%7C0%7C&amp;chdlp=r&amp;chdl=San%7CSite%7CAtendimento&amp;chco=ff8a00%2C585857%2C5501ff&amp;chd=e%3Af.f.f.f.f.f.f.%2Cf.f.f.f.f.f.f.%2Cf.f.f.f.f.f.f.
```

Comment: Google actually has an API for creating image charts. I don't know if is deprecated already.

Comment: This API was deprecated on April 20, 2012. There is a new charting API but it does not support static images.

Comment: Great, about the old API. What is wrong with [this](https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=p3&chd=t:60,40&chs=250x100&chl=Hello|World) kind of chart image?

Comment: I'm doing a dynamic e-mail with a lot of HTML. If I put the generated code of my google chart, the e-mail can't render the code. I need transform into an image.

Comment: UPDATED: I found  in https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/genericimagechart?hl=en a good way to transform into image. But I got a problem. I've created a variable in javascript that receives the HTML code of this chart image. OK, no problem. But I put this HTML code, in my code, where I create an e-mail dynamically. I receive the e-mail, but without the chart image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by following the steps on [this page](http://www.battlehorse.net/page/topics/charts/save_google_charts_as_image.html). Note that the code in the article is based on an old version of Google Visualization which used iframes, and will not work as posted. However, you can do the same using the following code (found in the comments):

```
var svg = $(chartContainer).find('svg').parent().html();
var doc = chartContainer.ownerDocument;
var canvas = doc.createElement('canvas');
canvas.setAttribute('style', 'position: absolute; ' + '');
doc.body.appendChild(canvas);
canvg(canvas, svg);
var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
canvas.parentNode.removeChild(canvas);
return imgData;
```

Note: I did not create this code, it was originally created by the author of the above site (Riccardo Govoni) and updated in the comments section by user Thomas.

Comment: svg element is not present in IE8 instead iframe element is present. then how can create image in IE8.

Comment: @Hari, please ask a separate question, comments are not the right place for that...

Answer (score 0):

You can get a PNG version of your chart using `chart.getImageURI()` like following:

Needs to be after the chart is drawn, so in the `ready` event!

```
var my_div = document.getElementById('my_div');
var my_chart = new google.visualization.ChartType(chart_div);

google.visualization.events.addListener(my_chart, 'ready', function () {
  my_div.innerHTML = '<img src="' + chart.getImageURI() + '">';
});

my_chart.draw(data);
```