# GAS - Chart API Deprecated

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-visualization, google-sheets-api

I looked at my 'Execution Hints' and saw this.

"Chart API is deprecated."

I copied the chart codes directly from here

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/column-chart-builder

What am I to change it to if it is deprecated?

I use the charts as images and send it to emails.

Comment: Does this question help?  [StackOverflow - Convert chart to image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14631821/converting-google-chart-into-image)  I'm just taking a wild guess.  My apologies if it's not what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct Google has [Deprecated](https://developers.google.com/chart/image/) Image Charts. It was officially deprecated as of April 20, 2012 as far as I know there is nothing by Google to replace it.

you will need to find some other third party tool to suit your needs or create your own.

It appears it will stop working on April 20,2015

[Deprecation Policy](https://developers.google.com/chart/terms)

> Google will announce if it intends to discontinue or make backwards
>   incompatible changes to this API or Service. Google will use
>   commercially reasonable efforts to continue to operate those Google
>   Chart Tools versions and features identified at
>   http://developers.google.com/chart/chart-api-list without these
>   changes until April 20, 2015, unless (as Google determines in its
>   reasonable good faith judgment):
>
> required by law or third party relationship (including if there is a
>   change in applicable law or relationship), or doing so could create a
>   security risk or substantial economic or material technical burden.
>   The above policy is the "Deprecation Policy."

Comment: I came across this
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart

Is that a possible solution? But it has to be on web service right?

Comment: exactly the thing that was nice about image charts is it was hosted by Google so you didn't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the original poster is referring to a different Charting service.  This one being the one used with UiService in GAS.

UiService is the only place that Charts can be used.  And since UiService was deprecated as of Dec 11, 2014, it makes sense that UiService only features, such as Charts, would also be deprecated.

It it likely to be possible to use Google Charts with the new enhancements to the HtmlService.  The last time I tried to use Google Charts with HtmlService, it mostly worked.  I have not tried since they introduced the IFrame based Sandbox mode.

The UiService set of Charts was a subset of the Google Charts stuff (which itself I think it just a free serving of the charting stuff built into GWT).
So while how you set things up will be different, you should have feature parity once you migrate your application from UiService to HtmlService.

The Google Image Charts are older, static charts, and that does appear to be going away.  But again, that is just one small portion of what Google Charts as an offering is.