# Convert Google-chart web component to an image

Tags: java, google-chrome, web-applications, google-visualization, polymer

I'm using the google-chart web component and I was wondering if there was a way to convert the chart into an image please.
thanks,

**Example of the code :**

```
<google-chart
  type='pie'
  options='{"title": "Number Of Alarms per category"}'
  cols='[{"label":"category", "type":"string"}, {"label":"number",  "type":"number"}]'
  rows='[["Gold", 31],["Bronze", 28],["Silver", 31]]'>
</google-chart>
```

charts like this, I'm using *polymer* and it's a spring-boot webApp,

and what I actually want is getting these charts as images to put them in a pdf file that my app would send to the user by mail.

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)
Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve] of the code
that you are having problems with, then we can try to help
with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting Google Chart into Image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14631821/converting-google-chart-into-image)

Comment: not exactly the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example of your code shouldnt be bad. Anyways there is a way to convert a chart to an image:

```
var my_div = document.getElementById('chart_div');
var my_chart = new google.visualization.ChartType(chart_div);

google.visualization.events.addListener(my_chart, 'ready', function () {
  my_div.innerHTML = '<img src="' + chart.getImageURI() + '">';
});

my_chart.draw(data);
```

Documentation: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/printing

Comment: I saw this, but this I think it just prints the chart as picture, no? I want to save the chart as a picture and put it on a pdf

Answer (score 1):

Try the getImageURI method of the component, which is a wrapper of the charts native getImageURI method:

https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/google-chart#method-getImageURI

Selecting the component and calling getImageURI will return the image as base64 encoded string:

```
var chart = document.querySelector('google-chart'),
imageAsString = chart.getImageURI()
```